# Is that any potential memory leak or deadlock with following threading code?

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I have created a threading library and it is used in our company program and the program is a customized software which is in C++ based. As shown in the code below, there are some customized variable types, such as FloatM1D, Ints and etc.

In the threading library, i'm using pthread_create (can't use the newer threading option due the C++ based is in old version) to fire threads that do calculation, then store the results in dictionary for later use.

Multiple threads are fired at one-go (DoEVM routine as shown in the code will be called multiple times at upper level) and wait for each thread completion before retrieval of the result. The thread wait completion  (WaitThreadCompletion() as shown in the code) will be called only once.

After the retrieval of the results, I will cleanup all the dictionary.

**My problem is**, the calculation routine (VSA.calculateEvm() as shown in the code) in the thread is throwing segmentation error intermittently and caused my program hang when it tries to check the thread completion in pthread_join. And I have no access/visible to VSA.calculateEvm() routine because this came from third party library, thus can't debugged deeper.

The error:

> An invalid memory reference (segmentation violation) has occurred.

The code from the threading library is provided at below and need some help to check if there is any issue with it that can cause the segmentation error?

Any advise is welcome and thanks in advance.

```
#define PARALLEL_DEVM_VERSION 2.0
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <EVM.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

ThreadingModule EVMx;


void *thread_EVM(void *arg);

pthread_mutex_t lock_x = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock_y = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

/*THREAD SHARED DATA STRUCTURE*/
struct ThreadData
{
//Warning: Do not use custom variable types in struct, it does not work good with pthread 
    float                   if_Freq;
    float                   sample_Rate;  
    int                     tnum;    
    bool                    enable_Plots;         
    bool                    ResequenceIsNeeded;
    int                     if_Bin;
    int                     RAT;   
};
typedef struct ThreadData m_ThreadData_Type;

BoolS                   m_Parallel_EVM;
map<int, FloatM>        m_TnumVsDEVM_map;
map<int, FloatM1D>      m_Tnum_ReseqArray_map;
map<int, pthread_t>     m_TnumVsThreadIds_map;
map<int, FloatM>        m_TnumVsResDEVM_map;
map<int, int>           m_TnumVsUTPaver_map;
IntS                    m_tnum;

/*THREAD SHARED DATA - THESE HAVE TO USE WITH MUTEX LOCK */
FloatM1D                m_measArrayTmp;
FloatM1D                m_refArrayTmp;
UnsignedS               m_if_Bin;
UnsignedS               m_RAT;  
Dot11acChannelType      chan_Type;
Dot11PilotTracking      pilot_Tracking;
Dot11EqualizerTraining  EQ_Train;
Dot11Trigger            trig;    
StringS                 wave_ID;

/* RESERVED STRING */ 
IntS TEST_ID_PREFIX = 1000;

IntS    ResequenceTimeDomainToComplex(FloatM1D measArray, FloatM1D complexOutArray, const UnsignedS ifBin, const UnsignedS stride);
IntS    Evm (FloatM1D measArray, FloatM1D refArray, const Dot11acChannelType chanType,  const Dot11PilotTracking PILOT_TRACK, const FloatS ifFreq, const FloatS sampleRate, const Dot11EqualizerTraining EQ_TRAIN, const Dot11Trigger TRIGGER, OfdmEvmData &evmResults,  const BoolS enablePlots = false , const StringS plotTag = "");
BoolS   Init(int TestNum, FloatM1D resdevm, IntS resdevmIndex, BoolS enabledataPlots=false, BoolS enableEVMsweep=false, BoolS UTP_AVG=true, IntS NumOfAverage=1); 
void    WaitThreadCompletion(IntS &totalThreads);
void    PostThreadsCleanup();
map<int, FloatM>    GetDEVMs();
map<int, FloatM1D>  GetResDEVMs();

ThreadingModule::ThreadingModule()
{
        //empty constr
}


IntS ThreadingModule::ResequenceTimeDomainToComplex(FloatM1D measArray, FloatM1D &complexOutArray, const UnsignedS ifBin, const UnsignedS stride)
{    
   /**
   *  @brief  Resequence array wrapper. If in parallel mode, it will do it at EVM thread.
   *  @param  measArray               measured array.
   *  @param  complexOutArray         array
   *  @param  ifBin                   argument
   *  @param  stride                  argument
   *  @param  enableEVMsweep          argument
   *  @return Parallel EVM flag.
   */

    IntS rslt; 
    IntS ret;     


        /*## PARALLEL MODE ##*/      
        //Push the array to dictionary, resequence it later        
        if (!m_Tnum_ReseqArray_map.count(m_tnum)>0){
            m_Tnum_ReseqArray_map[m_tnum] = measArray;
            m_if_Bin = ifBin;
            m_RAT = stride;  
        } else {
            //Fail safe
            ERR.ReportError(ERR_GENERIC_WARNING,"Duplicated TNUM found in the dictionary in ResequenceTimeDomainToComplex.",UTL_VOID, NO_SITES, UTL_VOID);
        }         


    return rslt;
}

IntS ThreadingModule::DoEvm(FloatM1D measArray, FloatM1D refArray,const Dot11acChannelType chanType,  const Dot11PilotTracking PILOT_TRACK, const FloatS ifFreq, const FloatS sampleRate, const Dot11EqualizerTraining EQ_TRAIN, const Dot11Trigger TRIGGER, OfdmEvmData &evmResults, const BoolS enablePlots, const StringS plotTag)
{
   /**
   *  @brief  EVM wrapper. 
   *  @param  measArray               measured array.
   *  @param  refArray                reference array.
   *  @param  chanType                channel type.
   *  @param  PILOT_TRACK             pilot tracking
   *  @param  ifFreq                  IF freq.
   *  @param  sampleRate EVM flag     sample rate.
   *  @param  Dot11EqualizerTraining  equalizer training.
   *  @param  Dot11Trigger            trigger.
   *  @param  OfdmEvmData             devm results.
   *  @param  enablePlots             enable plots
   *  @param  plotTag                 plot tagging.
   *  @return Ints                    not using.
   *
   */

    IntS        rslt, ret;
    BoolS       m_isResequenceNeeded(false);
    FloatM1D    m_tmp_meas_Arr;
    UnsignedS   m_tmpifBin(0);
    UnsignedS   m_tmpRAT(0);
    IntS        m_tmp_tnum; 


        /*## PARALLEL MODE ##*/  
        /*  check if resequence array is needed */
        if(m_Tnum_ReseqArray_map.count(m_tnum)>0){
            m_isResequenceNeeded=true;
            m_tmp_meas_Arr=m_Tnum_ReseqArray_map[m_tnum];
            m_tmpifBin= m_if_Bin;
            m_tmpRAT=m_RAT;
            m_Tnum_ReseqArray_map.erase(m_tnum);
        }       

        /* instantiate the structure */
        m_ThreadData_Type *tdata;     
        tdata =(m_ThreadData_Type *)malloc(sizeof (m_ThreadData_Type));

        /* mutex lock to initialize all thread shared variables */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_y);    
        m_measArrayTmp = m_isResequenceNeeded ? m_tmp_meas_Arr : measArray;         
        m_refArrayTmp = refArray;    
        chan_Type =  chanType;   
        pilot_Tracking = PILOT_TRACK;    
        EQ_Train = EQ_TRAIN;
        trig = TRIGGER;
        wave_ID = plotTag;               
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock_y);  

        /* thread specific data */
        tdata->if_Freq = ifFreq;
        tdata->sample_Rate = sampleRate;
        tdata->enable_Plots = enablePlots;     
        tdata->tnum = m_tnum;     
        tdata->ResequenceIsNeeded=m_isResequenceNeeded; 
        tdata->if_Bin = m_tmpifBin;
        tdata->RAT = m_tmpRAT;    

        /* create thread */
         ret = pthread_create(&m_TnumVsThreadIds_map[m_tnum], NULL, thread_EVM, (void*) tdata);    
         if (ret!=0) ERR.ReportError(ERR_GENERIC_WARNING , "Error in create EVM thread for TNUM="+ m_tnum.GetText()+".", ret, NO_SITES, UTL_VOID);         

    return rslt;
}


void* thread_EVM(void* arg)
{
   /**
   *  @brief  EVM wrapper. 
   *  @param  arg                     Arguments passed in with structure
   *
   */

    FloatM1D                m_meas_Arr;     
    FloatM1D                m_ref_Arr;
    FloatM1D                m_cmplx_Arr;
    Dot11acChannelType      m_chan_Type;
    Dot11PilotTracking      m_pilot_Tracking;
    FloatS                  m_freq;
    FloatS                  m_sample_Rate;
    Dot11EqualizerTraining  m_EQ_Train;
    Dot11Trigger            m_trig;    
    IntS                    m_testnum;    
    BoolS                   m_enable_Plots;
    StringS                 m_wave_ID;    
    OfdmEvmData             m_evm_Results;
    UnsignedS               m_Bin;
    UnsignedS               m_RAT;    
    BoolS                   m_isResequencedNeeded(false);   


    /* initialize all the local variables from arg */            
    m_ThreadData_Type *tdata;
    tdata=(m_ThreadData_Type*)arg;   

    /* mutex lock to retrieve thread shared data */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_y);   
    m_meas_Arr = m_measArrayTmp;                  
    m_ref_Arr =  m_refArrayTmp;                 
    m_pilot_Tracking = pilot_Tracking; 
    m_EQ_Train = EQ_Train;
    m_chan_Type = chan_Type; 
    m_trig = trig;
    m_wave_ID = wave_ID;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock_y); 

    /* initialize thread specific data */   
    m_freq = tdata->if_Freq;   
    m_sample_Rate = tdata->sample_Rate;
    m_testnum = tdata->tnum;        
    m_enable_Plots = tdata->enable_Plots;
    m_Bin = tdata->if_Bin;
    m_RAT = tdata->RAT;
    m_isResequencedNeeded = tdata->ResequenceIsNeeded;

    /* check if resequence array is needed */
    if (m_isResequencedNeeded){        
        m_cmplx_Arr.Resize(m_ref_Arr.GetSize());       
        VSA.DOT11.AC.ResequenceTimeDomainToComplex(m_meas_Arr, m_cmplx_Arr, m_Bin, m_RAT);        
        m_meas_Arr=m_cmplx_Arr;             
    }    

    /* perform evm calculation */
    VSA.calculateEvm(m_meas_Arr, m_ref_Arr, m_chan_Type, m_pilot_Tracking, m_freq, m_sample_Rate, m_EQ_Train, m_trig, m_evm_Results, m_enable_Plots, m_wave_ID); 

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_x);
    m_TnumVsDEVM_map[m_testnum]= m_evm_Results.evm; 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock_x);

    free(tdata);     

    return NULL;
}


void ThreadingModule::WaitThreadCompletion(IntS &totalThreads)
{
   /**
   *  @brief  Check all the created threads are complete. 
   *  @param  totalThreads        Total number of created threads.
   *
   */

    int ret; 
    map<int, pthread_t>::iterator itr;
    IntS tnum;
    pthread_t threadiD;

    /* check each threads if completed */
    for (itr = m_TnumVsThreadIds_map.begin(); itr != m_TnumVsThreadIds_map.end(); ++itr) { 
         tnum = itr->first;
         threadiD = itr->second;         
         ret=pthread_join(threadiD, NULL);
         if (ret!=0) ERR.ReportError(ERR_GENERIC_WARNING , "Can't complete the thread for TNUM="+ tnum.GetText()+".", UTL_VOID, NO_SITES, UTL_VOID);         
    }
    totalThreads = m_TnumVsThreadIds_map.size();
}

map<int, FloatM> ThreadingModule::GetDEVMs()
{ 
    return m_TnumVsDEVM_map;
}

map<int, FloatM> ThreadingModule::GetResDEVMs()
{ 
    return m_TnumVsResDEVM_map;
}

void ThreadingModule::PostThreadsCleanup()
{
   /**
   *  @brief  Post threads completion cleanup. Make sure to run this only after datalog the results.
   *  WARNING: Only call this routine when all threads complete executed.
   */
    TEST_ID_PREFIX =1000;

    m_TnumVsDEVM_map.clear();
    m_Tnum_ReseqArray_map.clear();
    m_TnumVsThreadIds_map.clear();
    m_TnumVsResDEVM_map.clear();
    m_TnumVsUTPaver_map.clear();

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_y);    
    m_measArrayTmp.Clear();
    m_refArrayTmp.Clear();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock_y);    
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us what compiler, which c++ version and operating system are you using?

Comment: [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) and a debugger are both your friends for rooting out issues like this. Regardless, whatever fires GetDEVMs() is reaping a value copy off that map without it being locked first. Thats' a big no-no. Lock the mtx, copy to local, unlock, and return the local. note: possible exception toss on that operation will orphan the mutex, so either catch it or make a poor-mans scope lock to handle that case.

Comment: Of what I can tell you after a quick review. Yes, you probably have some issues, but I can't tell you for sure, without the declaration of the class.

Comment: @skratchi.at I was not able to tell what compiler is the customized software as this came from third party. All the compilation is done in that software. For the C++ version, i think it is 15 and i'm running linux OS.
For the declaration of the class, are you referring the header for this library?

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks for the pointing out the issue on GetDEVMs(). Will correct it!

Comment: @KokCheowYeoh I'm not aware of c++15. Starting with version 03, there are 11, 14 and 17.

Comment: @skratchi.at I did a cc -v in the terminal and it shows the GCC version is 4.6.6 which i believes it is C++11.

Comment: @KokCheowYeoh It still depends on your compilation flags. Never the less, with 
c++11 there a many fancy threading features. I don't get it, why you are restricted, to `pthread`s. Most of the needed features are implemented in gcc 4.6

Comment: @skratchi.at can you please provide some threading features that is available to GCC 4.6? I will try that in the customized software and see if it's working.
Separately, can you please help to review my code above and see if there is any issue with the structure that can potential lead to the memory error that I'm getting?

Comment: There's quite a lot of code there for us to debug by inspection. If you want us to do your debugging for you you need to provide a compilable [mre].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.